# How to turn prolog predicates into JSON?

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

I wonder if there's a way to return a JSON object in SWI-Prolog, such that the predicate names become the keys, and the instantiated variables become the values. For example:

```
get_fruit(JS_out):-
    apple(A),
    pear(P),
    to_json(..., JS_out). # How to write this part?

apple("Gala").
pear("Bartlett").
```

I'm expecting `JS_out` to be:

```
JS_out = {"apple": "Gala", "pear": "Bartlett"}.
```

I couldn't figure out how to achieve this by using `prolog_to_json/3` or other built-in functions. While there are lost of posts on reading Json into Prolog, I can't find many for the other way around. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If `apple` and `pear` are hardcoded facts as you show, then obviously you need to pass just `A` and `P` to your `to_json` predicate. The predicate becomes trivial at that point: `to_json(A, P, {apple: A, pear: P}).`

Comment: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2 this might help ?

Comment: Thank you everyone! You are right @lurker. What you pointed out is obvious and important. Hardcoding is the way in my case. The answer is simply: `get_fruit(JS_out):- apple(A), pear(P), JS_out is {"apple": A, "pear": B}.`  Any idea how to do it if we don't know how many or what predicates there are?

Comment: Oh no, not `is`. The answer is as I showed you. You do not even need a variable. But if you want the variable, use `JS_out = ...` not `JS_out is ...`. `is/2` is for arithmetic expression evaluation. It will generate an error in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given hard coded facts as shown, the simple solution is:

```
get_fruit(JS_out) :- apple(A), pear(P), JS_out = {"apple" : A, "pear": B}.
```

However, in Prolog, you don't need the extra variable. You can write this as:

```
get_fruit({"apple" : A, "pear": B}) :- apple(A), pear(P).
```

You could generalize this somewhat based upon two fruits of any kind:

```
get_fruit(Fruit1, Fruit2, {Fruit1 : A, Fruit2 : B}) :-
    call(Fruit1, A),
    call(Fruit2, B).
```

With a bit more work, it could be generalized to any number of fruits.

As an aside, it is a common beginner's mistake to think that `is/2` is some kind of general assignment operator, but it is not. It is strictly for arithmetic expression evaluation and assumes that the second argument is a fully instantiated and evaluable arithmetic expression using arithmetic operators supported by Prolog. The first argument is a variable or a numeric value. Anything not meeting these criteria will always fail or generate an error.